# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186) UnhandledException: SocketException:OSError:No route to host, errno=113,address = xxx.xxx.xx.xx,port= XXXXX

Tags: android, flutter, localhost, socketexception

Future fetchusers() async{

```
String baseUrl = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";
print("before url hit");
final response = await http.get(Uri.http(baseUrl, "tuts/api"));
// final response = await http.get(Uri.http(baseUrl,'tuts/api/index.php'));
var Users = List<user_model>();
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  var usersJson = json.decode(response.body);
  for(var userJson in usersJson){
    Users.add(user_model.fromJson(userJson));
  }
}
if(response.statusCode ==404){
  print(response.headers);
}
print(response.body);
return Users;
```

}

I tried to get data from an API which was return users data on postman. that api was hosted as localhost.
my laptop and mobile network is same and i used machine address instead of 127.0.0.1 but, in flutter I can't find out any way to show data from.
I also set android internet permission in android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml.
but nothing work for me.
I am looking forward to hear solution!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in application tag and try.

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >
        <activity>
        ...
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I tried but same errorE/flutter (25184): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 192.168.31.12, port = 45380

Comment: I find out solution that is not in flutter side this bug is on xampp localhost side. I click Apache config button on xampp control panel and select httpd.conf file to edit and set localhost port 80 to 8000. after that I restart xampp and in flutter add port no 8000 with base url of my api. that worked for me.

Comment: Ya you don't entered a port so I told you that solution. There are some well-know port (means registered port for protocols). So 80 is for http and 443 for https so you cant use that without root user or HTTP server like apache or nginx.